# How to set up a volume linked to S3 in Docker Cloud with AWS?

Tags: amazon-s3, docker, rancher, docker-cloud

I'm running my Play! webapp with Docker Cloud (could also use Rancher) and AWS and I'd like to store all the logs in S3 (via volume). Any ideas on how I could achieve that with minimal effort?

Answer (score 2):

Use `docker volumes` to store the logs in the host system.

Try `S3 aws-cli` to sync your local directory with `S3 Bucket`

```
aws s3 sync /var/logs/container-logs s3://bucket/
```

create a `cron` to run it on every minute or so.

Reference: [s3 aws-cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/)

Comment: Thanks, but can you think of a way without tinkering with the host system? It's not straight forward with the default ami provided by Docker Cloud. Any experience with https://hub.docker.com/r/dockercloud/dockup ?

Comment: not sure why you downvoted - this seems like the simplest solution IMO - just use a docker based version of aws-cli like: https://github.com/xueshanf/docker-awscli and write a bash script to backup the volume mount to s3 every x seconds, then sleep x seconds, rinse repeat...

also - not sure what your container is running, but you should have logging solutions available to write to s3 - here's one for nodejs apps - https://github.com/coggle/s3-streamlogger

Comment: I didn't downvote. I would hope there is some other solution less hacky though